# Is 2 return in a switch function valid code?

Tags: php, switch-statement

```
function getFileExtension($fileType)
{
    switch($fileType)
    {
        case "image/png":
            return "png";
            return true;
            break;

        case "image/png":
            return "x-png";
            return true;
            break;

        case "mage/pjpeg":
            return "jpg";
            return true;
            break;

        case "image/jpeg":
            return "jpg";
            return true;
            break;

         default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Second return in each case will never run (`break` too). It's dead code (can be simply removed).

Answer (score 2):

2nd return statement will never be executed. If you want to return 2 values, return an array containing the 2 values..

```
function getFileExtension($fileType)
{
  $results = array();
  switch($fileType)
  {
    case "image/png":
        $results['type'] = "png";
        $results['status'] = true;
        break;

    case "image/png":
        $results['type'] = "x-png";
        $results['status'] = true;
        break;

    case "mage/pjpeg":
        $results['type'] = "jpg";
        $results['status'] = true;
        break;

    case "image/jpeg":
        $results['type'] = "jpg";
        $results['status'] = true;
        break;

     default:
        $results['type'] = "";
        $results['status'] = false;
  }
  return $results;
}
```